# Авторизация к MS SQL в десктопном приложении

Tags: sql-server

Какой подход для авторизации лучше использовать?

1. Встроенная Windows
2. Авторизация SQL Server'a
3. Сочитание авторизации SQL Server'a и собственной - есть свои таблицы пользователй, ролей и т.д. а, например, для каждой роли создается одно имя входа.

Очень хотелось бы услышать мнение тех, кто сталкивался с подобной задачей. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно создается один пользователь в sql-сервере, ему даются полные права на базу (одну - ту, с которой работает система), а разграничение прав и список пользователей ведется непосредственно в системе. Какая именно авторизация будет использоваться для этого одного пользователя sql-сервера непринципиально, может быть и пользователь из AD или свой sql'ый.

В любом случае в системе для пользователя будет храниться своя информация (профиль системных настроек, например), вполне разумно хранить и роли с правами там же, в системе. Тем более, что права пользователя не ограничиваются правами доступа к таблицам и операциями над ними. Там будут и ограничения на видимость определенных элементов управления и доступность отчетов и так далее.

Comment: А как быть если понадобится отслежваение изменений (кто и когда)? В случае с Windows или MS SQL авторизацией проблем никаких - получаем имя пользователя и все. Тогда как в случае с собственной системой придется для каждой таблицы создавать поле последнего редактировавшего, чтобы была возможность передать его идентификатор в конструкциях INSERT\UPDATE для дальнейшей оработки, например в триггере

Comment: Система контроля изменений может быть довольно сложной. Кто и когда - это самый простой случай, которго может быть недостаточно, и придется создавать журналы изменений и т.д. И тогда лучше работать со своими данными, а не с пользователями mssql. Да, если есть необходимость в контроле изменений, триггеры - правильное решение.  
Кроме того есть еще причина использовать своих пользователей - это заведение новых и редактирование существующих (правка ролей и т.д.). Легче это делать в программе, чем звать DBA, который добавит пользователя в mssql или что-то поправит.

Comment: Кроме того, представьте, что базу вам надо перенести на другой сервак, вам придется опять мучиться с переносом пользователей и ролей - та еще радость...